# Optimize dataframe fill and refill Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have changed the column names and have added new columns too.
I am having a numpy array that I have to fill in the respective dataframe columns.
I am getting a delayed response in filling the dataframe using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
df = df.tail(1000)
DISPLAY_IN_TRAINING = []
Slice_Middle_Piece_X = slice(None,-1, None)
Slice_Middle_Piece_Y = slice(-1, None)
input_slicer = slice(None, None)
output_slice = slice(None, None)

seq_len                     = 15            # choose sequence length
n_steps                     = seq_len - 1
Disp_Data = df


def Generate_DataSet(stock, 
                     df_clone,
                     seq_len
                    ):
    global DISPLAY_IN_TRAINING
    data_raw = stock.values # convert to numpy array
    
    data = []
    len_data_raw = data_raw.shape[0]
    
    for index in range(0, len_data_raw - seq_len + 1): 
        data.append(data_raw[index: index + seq_len])
    
    data = np.array(data);
    
    test_set_size = int(np.round(30 / 100 * data.shape[0]));
    train_set_size = data.shape[0] - test_set_size;
    
    x_train, y_train    = Get_Data_Chopped(data[:train_set_size])
    print("Training Sliced Successful....!")
    
    df_train_candle         = df_clone[n_steps : train_set_size + n_steps]
    
    if len(DISPLAY_IN_TRAINING) == 0:
        DISPLAY_IN_TRAINING = list(df_clone)
       
    df_train_candle.columns = DISPLAY_IN_TRAINING
    return [x_train, y_train, df_train_candle]
 
        
def Get_Data_Chopped(data_related_to):
    x_values = []
    y_values = []
    
    for index,iter_values in enumerate(data_related_to):
        x_values.append(iter_values[Slice_Middle_Piece_X,input_slicer])
        y_values.append([item for sublist in iter_values[Slice_Middle_Piece_Y,output_slice] for item in sublist])
        
    x_values = np.asarray(x_values)
    y_values = np.asarray(y_values)
    return [x_values,y_values]    

x_train, y_train, df_train_candle = Generate_DataSet(df, 
                                                     Disp_Data, 
                                                     seq_len
                                                    )

df_train_candle.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

df_columns = list(df_train_candle)
df_outputs_name = []

OUTPUT_COLUMN = df.columns

for output_column_name in OUTPUT_COLUMN:
    df_outputs_name.append(output_column_name + "_pred")
    for i in range(len(df_columns)):
        if df_columns[i] == output_column_name:
            df_columns[i] = output_column_name + "_orig"
            break
            
df_train_candle.columns = df_columns

df_pred_names = pd.DataFrame(columns = df_outputs_name)
df_train_candle = df_train_candle.join(df_pred_names, how="outer")

for row_index, row_value in enumerate(y_train):
    for valueindex, output_label in enumerate(OUTPUT_COLUMN):
        df_train_candle.loc[row_index, output_label + "_orig"] = row_value[valueindex]
        df_train_candle.loc[row_index, output_label + "_pred"] = row_value[valueindex]

print(df_train_candle.head())
```

The shape of my `y_train` is (195, 24) and the dataframe shape is (195, 48). Now I am trying to optimize and make the process work faster. The `y_train` may change shape to say `(195, 1)` or `(195, 5)`.

So please can someone tell me what other way (optimized way) for doing the above process? I want a general solution that could fit anything without loosing the data integrity and is faster too.

If teh data size increases from 1000 to 2000 the process become slow. Please advise how to make it faster.
Sample Data `df` looks like this with shape `(1000, 8)`

```
         A    B    C    D   E   F   G   H
64272  195  215  239  272  22  11  33  55
64273  196  216  240  273  22  11  33  55
64274  197  217  241  274  22  11  33  55
64275  198  218  242  275  22  11  33  55
64276  199  219  243  276  22  11  33  55
```

The output looks like this:

```
   A_orig  B_orig  C_orig  D_orig  E_orig  F_orig  G_orig  H_orig A_pred B_pred C_pred D_pred E_pred F_pred G_pred H_pred
0      10      30      54      87      22      11      33      55     10     30     54     87     22     11     33     55
1      11      31      55      88      22      11      33      55     11     31     55     88     22     11     33     55
2      12      32      56      89      22      11      33      55     12     32     56     89     22     11     33     55
3      13      33      57      90      22      11      33      55     13     33     57     90     22     11     33     55
4      14      34      58      91      22      11      33      55     14     34     58     91     22     11     33     55
```

Please generate csv columns with 1000 or more lines and see that the program becomes slower. I want to make it faster. I hope this is good to go for understanding.

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is a follow up of another one, but it is clearly not self-sufficient. There is no reproducible data provided, no explanation of the background nor the expected output. One sure thing, if you used nested `for` loops to modify a DataFrame, this will be incredibly slow…

Comment: I don't `y_train` in the sample code

Comment: Okay I have updated my question with workable sample

Comment: I hope that this will help you understand the problem I am facing and hope you can advise me to make it faster

Comment: @mozway Can you please advise me regarding the answer or still there is something missing? Do let me know.

Comment: @hpaulj please can you tell me what I can do to make the process work faster?